# "msg.value" used in non-payable function. Do you want to add the "payable" modifier to this function? msg.value); ^-------^

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm a beginner of solidity. I just want to test view the event in etherscan but above error problems up.

```
contract class24{
    function get_time_now()public view returns(uint256,uint256){
        return (now,block.timestamp);
    }
    function get_block_info()public view returns(uint blockNumber,bytes32 blockHash,uint256  blockDifficulty){

        return (block.number,
                blockhash(block.number-1),
                block.difficulty);
    }
    function get_tx_info()public view returns(address msgSender,address origin,uint value){
        return (msg.sender,
                tx.origin,
                msg.value);
    }
    event setMoney (uint money);

    function buy () public payable {
        emit setMoney(msg.value);
    }
}
```

However, when I force to deploy the contract by matamask in Rinkeby test network.I'm 100% sure that my wallet has enough eth. The below warning prompt up. Could any tell me why and what can I do?

*Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted*

Answer (score 2):

If this happens during deployment of the contract, you are probably trying to send some eth alongside the contract deployment transaction.

The "only" way to send eth to a contract is to call a function that has `payable` modifier: https://solidity-by-example.org/payable/

When you're deploying the contract, you are in fact calling a special function called `constructor`. Which is a function that can be called only once, during the contract deployment. But your contract doesn't have one, does it?

In fact it does. Every contract, if not manually defined, has a default empty constructor like this:

```
constructor() {
}
```

You can see it has no `payable` modifier, so that means, the contract cannot receive funds during its deployment. If you want to send some initial funds to the constract during deployment, you would have to manually define the constructor and add the `payable` modifier.

In your case, you're probably don't want to send any funds to the contract right now, so you'll need to remove the `value` amount from your transaction.

If you're working in Remix, the value is defined here and needs to be set to 0: [image]

Comment: The contract is fine to deploy if I don't put any value in remix. However, what I really want to do is, put 1eth in the value in remix and successful deploy the contract.

However, when I put 1 eht in the value the warning message - "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? execution reverted" prompt up and remix shows "transaction execution failed".....

Comment: Like I said, if you want to send eth to the contract during deployment, you need to define the constructor and add a `payable` modifier to it: `constructor() payable { }`

Comment: Do you have any idea what happen on it?

Comment: What do you mean? You just cannot send eth to a function that doesn't have `payable` modifier.